# testing if constructor in constructor chain

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to implement a GTK+ inspired widget toolkit for the web in JavaScript. One of the constructor chains goes

```
gtk.widget => gtk.container => gtk.bin => gtk.window
```

Every `gtk.widget` has a `showAll` method, which, if and only if the `widget` is a `gtk.container` or derivative (such as `gtk.bin` or `gtk.window`), will recursively show the children of that widget. Obviously, if it isn't a `gtk.container` or derivative, we shouldn't do anything because the widget in question can't contain anything.

For reference, here is my inheritance function; it's probably not the best, but it's a start:

```
function inherit(target, parent) {
    target.prototype = new parent;
    target.prototype.constructor = target;
}
```

I know that I can check for the direct constructor like this:

```
if (this.constructor === gtk.container) ...
```

However, this only tests for direct construction and not, say, if the object is a `gtk.bin` or `gtk.window`. How can I test whether `gtk.container` is somewhere up in the constructor chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof) operator:

```
if (this instanceof gtk.container) ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `instanceof` would check through the constructor chain.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: no problem, and thanks for fixing my typo :-)